# How can I set up the y value of a matplotlib grid of 2x2 to a shared constant?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I am currently working on a project that will plot the data collected from a accelerometer. In order to get a good insight of what we will do I need to plot the data as a grid which I have done with matplotlib:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[0, 0].set_title("Non Faulty Acc X Data")
axs[0, 1].plot(x2, y2, 'tab:orange')
axs[0, 1].set_title('Non Faulty Acc X Data')
axs[1, 0].plot(x3, y3, 'tab:green')
axs[1, 0].set_title('Faulty Acc X Data')
axs[1, 1].plot(x4, y4, 'tab:red')
axs[1, 1].set_title('Faulty Acc X Data')
```

With this code I get the following output.
[Image of the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27AnP.png)

As you can see, the y-value (time) is not the same between both graphs.
I have tried this code:

```
plt.ylim([0, 1])
```

I have both tried it as seperate after each `.set_title` and `.plot` methods. And I have tried using it in the for loop as well:

```
for ax in axs.flat:
    plt.ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set(ylabel='Time')
```

After that nothing changes.
I basically need the second graphs y-values to be able to match the y-values of the first one to get an accurate output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib's [subplots()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) has the `sharex` and `sharey` parameters that align the axes to the same range automatically.

So in your case, you should simply use `subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Brendan's answer works perfectly, but a simpler way is to specify `sharey=True` in the keyword arguments to `plt.subplots`:

```
plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)
```